# How to move map (within WKWebView) with one finger instead of two fingers

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, wkwebview

I am new to iOS mobile app development. In my app, we have WKWebView, within which we display google map. Currently, it requires two fingers to move the map. How do I change that behavior and make the map move with one finger?

Comment: map move only one finger by default

Comment: @Ishegg - We are showing our mobile website (which has googleMaps) in WKWebView. we are not rendering google map using native code.

Comment: @Sagar - I used webView earlier in my app, that time, I could move Map with one finger but after implementing WKWebView, it shows background message that "Use two fingers to move the map". if Map move by one finger is default behavior, what causes two finger behavior??

Comment: @SRM that's what I meant. Check my answer (and comment there), you need to make these adjustments I mention on your website. The default behavior is **two** fingers for scrolling websites, not one.

Comment: We tried but that but didn't help. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have access to the map code? On scrollable pages, `gestureHandling` is set to `cooperative` [by default](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction). This means, you need two fingers to pan the map. To get this working, you need to set `gestureHandling` to `greedy`, which will allow your users to pan the map with only one finger. Test it out first though, since this is set to `cooperative` for a reason. It can be very annoying to be scrolling down on a website and having your scroll be hijacked by a map you didn't mean to scroll.

```
function initMap() {
    var locationRio = {lat: -22.915, lng: -43.197};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 13,
        center: locationRio,
        gestureHandling: 'greedy'
    });
}
```